# Get position of clicked element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to scroll to get an item into view when it's clicked, however I cannot manage to get it's top position on click:

This is what I'm trying right now:

```
    $( "section" ).click(function(e) {
        console.log("thing top: "+$(this).position().top);
        //$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        //return false; 
    });
```

However I always get the same top position, now matter what element is clicked. How can I do this right?

Comment: Show your html please.

Comment: sorry, I found the mistake, I'm using wordpress and the theme was wrapping everything in a section element. Not sure how to proceed. The snippet given is the right answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `$(this).offset().top` as it gets the position relative to the document rather than the parent

[Offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
```